# In Batch, how can I combine variables to name a folder?

Tags: batch, batch-file

How can I combine variables to name a folder?

Here is my current code. My script has delayedexpansion enabled:

```
mkdir "%myPath%\"%Letter%""!Number!""
```

Comment: Are you using delayed variable expansion? If so, that needs to be mentioned in your question.

Comment: Yes, I'm using delayed variable expansion. I've added it to the question.

Comment: Use only one pair of double quotes enclosing the whole path => `mkdir "%myPath%\%Letter%!Number!""` If you aren't sure when to use the exclamation mark instead of a percent sign, here you ***can*** use it for all vars.

Answer (score 1):

You only need a single set of double-quotes, like this:

```
mkdir "%myPath%\%Letter%!Number!"
```

Sometimes it helps make your code more readable by building your variables in stages. For example:

```
Set Fullpath=%myPath%\%Letter%
MkDir "%Fullpath%!Number!"
```

Note that when using this approach it's typically best to not put the double-quotes into the variables containing path elements and only include them in the actual executing commands. This reduces confusion and adds the flexibility of allowing you to combine variables containing path elements in various ways without having to worry about ending up with too many quotes as was the problem with your original statement.